# Show only the first column which has the same value on next record

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table

```
name ----------------------- phone ------------------------ address

Aldi ----------------------- 021345 ----------------------- Bogor

Aldi ------------------------021345 ----------------------- Jakarta

John ------------------------034566 ----------------------- Depok
```

How to show only the first column if it has a same value at the next record? The result may looks like :

```
name ----------------------- phone ------------------------ address

Aldi ----------------------- 021345 ----------------------- Bogor

----------------------------------------------------------- Jakarta

John ----------------------- 034566 ----------------------- Depok
```

Comment: Try this for your tables http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html just paste it in as unicode and make it a code block

Comment: It sounds like you need a reporting tool. SQL is going to return data in a tabular format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  this

[Sql fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09940/2)

```
select t1.id,
case when t1.name = t2.name and t1.phone = t2.phone
then
'-'
else
t1.name
end as name,
case when t1.name = t2.name and t1.phone = t2.phone
then
'-'
else
t1.phone
end as phone,t1.address from test t1 left join test t2 on t2.id = t1.id-1
order by t1.id
```

Comment: by the way, I need to remove `... and t1.phone = t2.phone`